# Read all input to strings, separated by whitespace

Tags: c++, string, stdin, cin

I'm trying to get all buffered input from `cin`. I tried `getline`, but it only lets me choose one delimiting character. I tried `operator>>`, but `while(cin >> str)` didn't work for me. Any suggestions?

PS I haven't looked at boost yet but I'm looking now. I'll let you know if I find anything.

Comment: How doesn't `while(cin>>str)` work? What do you get that you don't expect?

Comment: It never stops inputing; that is, the loop never ends.

Comment: You need to signal the "end of input" by typing Ctrl-Z on a line by itself (in Windows. I don't know about linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control-D on unix/mac and Control-Z on Widows signals an end-of-input to cin.